# Creating multiple variables from existing variable

Tags: loops, variables

I would like to create multiple variables from already existing variable from the dataset.

For example let’s say that the variable x has value from 1 to 10.

I want to create variable
If x=1 then x1=1
Else x1= 2

If x=2 then x2=1
Else x2= 2

And so on until variable x10.

Is there any loop that would create variables?

If it is feasible, is there also way to create variables with the original variable value not increment by 1?
(Eg. Variable x has value 11,12,22,35, 57)

Thanks in advance

Create each variable without loop